# Add text to text area using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

How can I add custom text to already written text in textarea using javascript??Thanks...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
function addText(elId,text) {
    document.getElementById(elId).value += text;
}
```

or:

```
function addText(elId,text) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(elId);
    var txt = document.createTextNode(text);
    obj.appendChild(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myTextarea.value += "text to add to the textarea"
```

Comment: what is myTextarea in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Grab the existing text in the textarea (the element's .value)

Combine your existing text (append, prepend, insert, or whatever you need)

Write the result back to the textarea.

Tah-dah!